# How to install Weechat?

Tags: cygwin, weechat

I must admit i'm not much of a coder or computer scientist, but in the past a friend installed Weechat on my windows computer using Cygwin (via the Cygwin terminal of course). I have a new computer now thats running windows 8.1 and have installed Cygwin with all of the necessary packages, and downloaded the latest stable version of Weechat (1.2). I am stuck from there though and don't really know which direction to move in, the only thing I have done with Cygwin so far is moved the home terminal folder to a more easier accessible location. Would it be possible to get a step by step walkthrough of how the installation progresses after downloading both the Cygwin component and the Weechat files and scripts?

Answer (score 2):

Before we you can start using WeeChat, there are a few other pieces of software you need to install with CygWin. WeeChat relies on them for its functionality, which is why they are called *dependencies*.

You can find a detailed list of **dependencies** and further **instructions** on this link:
[Weechat on Windows](https://distanthought.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/enjoy-weechat-on-windows/)

Feel free to ask for further help if the above guide wouldn't suffice.

#### EDIT

WeeChat is currently available via the CygWin native repositories.
Simply search for `weechat` in the CygWin package manager.

*I already have CygWin installed, what now?*

No worries, simply rerun the `setup-x86-64.exe`* you've downloaded. This process won't remove any of your previously installed packages. At the end of the installation process you'll be able to look for and install WeeChat.
* (on 32-bit systems, the installer would be named `setup-x86.exe`)

Comment: I've already installed the dependencies, but am not sure where to go from there. Do I need to have the older (0.3.4) version of the weechat files in order to run them through Cygwin?

Comment: I keep getting "-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory" whenever trying to run the command "$ ./configure --prefix=/path/to/directory" What specifically is the directory path supposed to lead to?

Comment: The `--prefix=/path/to/directory` command should point to your the folder where you downloaded WeeChat. It needs to know, so it can compile it.

Comment: I put the command to the folder where I downloaded WeeChat (which was the download folder) and received ":bash: ./configure: No such file or directory" I tried it again but this time directing it specifically to the WeeChat folders itself, and received the same message. My initial command was " $ ./configure --prefix=/cygdrive/c/Users/Wyatt/Downloads"
        And the second and more specific one was "$ ./configure --prefix=C:\Users\Wyatt\Downloads\weechat-1.2" 
Perhaps there is a specific folder within the WeeChat folder I should be directing it to? If so I am not sure which one, or what file.

Comment: I don't have access to a system w/ CygWin at the moment to try this myself. I'll give it a go later today.

Comment: Thank you I would GREATLY appreciate it!

Comment: Something came up yesterday. I'm making time for it in a moment!

Comment: Thats fine, take your time. I've been trying to make headway on it myself but I think is is more complicated than I originally thought

Comment: Hi @Wyatt, you won't believe it, but WeeChat seems to be available through the native CygWin repositories these days.  
I've updated my answer to reflect that information.  

Have a good one!

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH Michiel I was able to install the package and be on my was as soon as it finished updating! I appreciate you taking the time out to help me!